# The minimum and maximum of a NumPy array are both NaN

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array that has a type of float32, but the minimum and maximum are both NaN. I also verified that it does not contain any NaNs or infinite values.

Comment: Can you include the portion of the array which is producing this? And the relevant code?

Comment: Please can you show us some of your code

Comment: It will be much easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: While dealing with arrays with NaN values (although you say it does not contain any) `np.nanmin` and `np.nanmax` can help you.

Comment: I checked the dtypes for the data frame. Each individual column is a 'float32', but the dtype for the whole frame is 'object'